# Font for Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want my keyboard layout as per Anmol Font. Can you please advise me how to do that?

[image: AnmolLipi KeyMap]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the program [KeyboardLayoutEditor](https://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor/).

In this program, you can directly drag and drop your characters from the character map. It is very comfortable for editing XKB layouts.